# How to Change Table Size using Skeleton CSS Framework

Tags: html, css, skeleton-css-boilerplate

I am  creating a table using the Skeleton CSS Framework as follows:

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>V1504 Currently Active Jobs</h2>
  <table class="u-full-width">
    <thead>
      <!-- table head -->
      <tr class="u-full-width">
        <!-- table row -->
        <th>Job Number</th>
        <th>Employee Name</th>
        <th>Department</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="job-list">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

The reason why the tbody is empty is because I dynamically insert elements to the table via Javascript. But the table looks like the following:

[image]

Now I want to increase the size of the fonts for the  table heading as well as its elements, how can this be done using Skeleton CSS if possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skeleton.css is a responsive framework.  If you want to change the predefined styles set out in Skeleton.css, the best option would be to setup and link a second stylesheet in the `<head>` of your HTML document and target these styles there.

For instance - setting the `.u-full-width th { font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; }` will set the font to 16px and bold for all `<th>` tags with a parent class of `.u-full-width`.